# Running Android Studio on Remote Desktop Terribly Slow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, remote-desktop

I am using Android Studio on Remote Desktop and it's terribly slow, even though the Windows VPS I am using has 8 virtual cores and 8 GBs of RAM. I've tried a million different speed optimizations that are out there on YouTube and just can't seem to figure it out.

When I am about to launch and AVD, I get an error: Your CPU does not support VT-x technology. So, I switch to the ARM and it takes 10 minutes to load the device, regardless of which one is it.

Remote Desktop Connection I am using is Windows 2012 R2.

Hyper-V is off so I don't know what else could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: suppose it refer to sharing remote pc system something like shared hosting

Comment: Yes, this is not a dedicated server. Is that the reason why I am experiencing this?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not quite sure